# python/django spawn background process and avoid zombie process

Tags: python, django, linux, fork, zombie-process

I need to spawn a background process in django, the view returns immediately, the background process continues make some changes, then update the db. This is done by `os.spawnl()` function to call a separate .py file.

The problem is after the background process is done, it becames a zombie function `[python] <defunct>`.

How do I avoid that? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972383/41948) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218394/41948) example but I still got the child process as zombie after the django render process.

I want to take this chance to practice my *nix process management skills so please do me a favor, don't give me Celery or other mq/async task solutions, and I hate dependencies.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait

Comment: @tMC thanks, should I `os.wait()` in child process or grandchild process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got to long for a comment-

The `wait` syscall (which `os.wait` is a wrapper for) reaps exit codes/pids from dead processes.  You will want to `os.wait` in the process that is a generation above your zombie processes; the parent of the zombies processes.  The parent processes will receive a `SIGCHLD` signal when one of its child processes die.  If you insist on doing all of this yourself, you will need to install a signal handler to trap for `SIGCHLD` and in the signal handler call `os.wait`.  Read some documentation on unix process handling and the Python documentation on the `os` module as there are variations of the `os.wait` function that will be non-blocking which maybe helpful.

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, lambda _x,_y: os.wait())
```

Comment: The problem is that signal.signal only works in the main thread, and django likes to keep that thread to itself. Otherwise, you could just do signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN) which won't leave the dead processes as zombies.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I used active_children() from multiprocessing module.

```
import multiprocessing

# somewhere in middleware or where appropriate call
active_children()
```